# Increasing Loop Efficiency

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, foreach, iteration

### Background

I have a table which contains a list of numbers. I retrieve this list and put it into a datatable. I then iterate though the rows in the table and display every number between 1000 and 9999 that isn't in the table.

### My Loop

```
static DataTable table = new DataTable();

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["stationid"]);

                for (int i = 1000; i < 9999 - table.Rows.Count; i = i++)
                {
                    if (i != id)
                    {

                                stationIdsTb.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                                stationIdsTb.Text += i.ToString();

                     }
                 }
             }
```

### Question

However this method does work. It is extremely slow.

**Is there a more efficient and quicker way of calculating the numbers between 1000 and 9999 that aren't in the datatable?**

Comment: Just to clarify, your code doesn't give the right result, right? Because what you described doesn't match your code. (And the first couple people to answer have suggested faster code, but the logic is mostly the same, so it will still not work).

Comment: @piojo, No it does give the right result, it just takes a long time. Perhaps i didn't explain properly. I wanted to display every number that isn't in the datatable and is between 1000 and 9999.

Comment: interesting. Are you sure? That code really looks like it would give every number between 1000 and 9999 multiple times, and those that are in the database would be given less, but they would still be given.

Comment: @piojo, Apologies. You are right. It does indeed produce multiple outputs of the same list.

Comment: Cool, then just pay more attention to the later answers--they took the time to notice the discrepancy. :)

Comment: @piojo, Would you mind giving me a clue to why it duplicates?

Comment: @KingCundy. Let's simplify. If you had a table with numbers 5 and 2, and you want to find missing compared to 1-10, your logic says: I have number 5. Between 1-(10-2), give me the numbers that aren't 5. That'll be 1,2,3,4,6,7,8. Next, I have number 2. What are the numbers of 1-(10-2) that aren't 2. That'll be 1,3,4,5,6,7,8. Put the two together, and the result is: 1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,7,8,8.

Comment: @steve16351, Makes perfect sense. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop isn't slow. But all these string concatenations are. As strings are immutable, your're creating a new `string` object with each concatenation, which needlessly copies memory around and adds a lot of GC pressure.

Use a `StringBuilder`:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["stationid"]);
    var max = Math.Max(9999, table.Rows.Count);

    for (int i = 1000; i < max; ++i)
    {
        if (i != id)
            sb.AppendLine().Append(i); // Or just sb.AppendLine(i); maybe?
    }
}

stationIdsTb.Text = sb.ToString();
```

On a side note, writing `i = i++` is *really* wrong, as it's basically a no-op.

---

Update:

> display every number between 1000 and 9999 that isn't in the table.

That's not exactly what your code is doing, but if it's really what you want, here's a simpler way:

```
var stationIds = new HashSet<int>(
    table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => Convert.ToInt32(row["stationid"]))
);

var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (var i = 1000; i <= 9999; ++i)
{
    if (!stationIds.Contains(i))
        sb.AppendLine(i);
}

stationIdsTb.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: 9 seconds too fast for me :-)

Comment: @Zohar hehe :-) but you should remove that `ToString` from `Append`, and I spotted that `i = i++` thing too ;-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, Although this is definitely a smarter and more efficient way of doing it.. There does't seem to be a massive reduction in the time it takes. The datatable contains 742 rows so the loop has to do 742 * 9999 = 7419258 iterations. which at the moment even with you improved routine takes about 5 mins on my i7 laptop.

Comment: @KingCundy I didn't want to alter your logic too much, does my update solve your issue and meet your needs?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski That answer update is total rip off of my answer :)

Comment: @msmolcic not even close ;-)

Comment: @msmolcic actually I didn't know about `PrimaryKey`, as I never use `DataTable`s anymore (to be honest I didn't see your answer when updating mine). Looking at the code, it doesn't use `HashSet` at all (that thing didn't exist in .NET 1.0), and I suppose my method will be faster, but didn't test it. Nevertheless, have a well-deserved upvote from me ;-)

Comment: Trying to work out exactly what my logic was doing? I've not come across a hash set before? This solution does however bring back the set of results in about 2 second, compared to the 5 minutes i was getting with my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `stationIdsTb.Text += ...` use a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["stationid"]);

    for (int i = 1000; i < 9999 - table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i != id)
        {
         sb.AppendLine().Append(i);
         }
    }
}

stationIdsTb.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to display numbers between 1000 and 9999 that aren't in table then you're doing it wrong. You could set *"stationid"* column as primary key and inside for loop see if primary key contains current number. Correct me if I got it wrong, but this should be right solution:

```
table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { table.Columns["stationid"] };

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1000; i <= 9999; i++)
{
    if (!table.Rows.Contains(i))
        sb.AppendLine(i);
}

stationIdsTb.Text = sb.ToString();
```

You could also do it this way after you set primary key:

```
stationIdsTb.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Range(1000, 9000).Where(number => !table.Rows.Contains(number)));
```

Comment: I think that should just be `sb.AppendLine(i);`.

Answer (score 0):

Many issues
1) Use linq in case you want in the front end
2) Don't use datatable. Also whatever columns needed, only select those so that datatable size will be less.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.. unless I miss something, don't understand the current method - let's say 1,000 isn't in the table - you'd end up checking for 1,000 and adding it to your result for every row in the table. I assume you want a distinct list of missing numbers.

```
// get all the numbers in the list
HashSet<int> numbersInTable = new HashSet<int>(dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(a => (int)a["StationId"]));

// between 1000-9999, find numbers not in the set
List<int> missingNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1000, 9000).Except(numbersInTable).ToList();

// convert to a string
string result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, missingNumbers.ConvertAll<string>(a => a.ToString()));
```